# Return the row with the max count without using a sub query

Tags: sql, h2

You got two relations 
**Party(id, name)** and **Delegate (id, party)**
Where the id's are primary keys, and the Attribute party in Delegate is a foreign key defined as follows:

> party int references Party

=> It is a C-CM relation. 
[C: A delegate **C**an have a Party, CM: A Party **C**an have **M**ultiple delegates]

Now how can you make out the party having the most delegates with SQL? [Without using subqueries or hacks like ordering and then cutting]

I found the following solution for only one entity: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/

My approach was something like

```
select p.name 
from Party p inner join Delegate d 
on p.id = d.party 
group by p.name 
having count(d.id) = MAXVALUE
```

Where MAXVALUE is something I don't know

Comment: Why don't you want to use a subquery? Would a derived table be OK?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Probably homework assignment

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name like sagi said, it was an allegation of a homework to not use sub queries. From my understanding derived tables include sub queries, so I don't think that would work

Comment: A derived table is conceptually something different than a sub-query. But I don't think is is solvable without using at least one of that. Btw: if you just started to learn SQL, you should _really_ get used to an explicit `JOIN` operator not the outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Here! Here! Emphasis on fragile, difficult to read, and occasionally even in violation of the spec (because of unexpectedly turning OUTER JOINS into INNER JOINS)..

Comment: Even select * from(SELECT..) is not allowed? Nothing seems to come to my mind on how to solve this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name corrected the notation to inner join

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the use of limit

```
select p.name,count(*) num
from Party p, Delegate d 
where p.id = d.party 
group by p.name 
order by num
limit 1;
```

or a select by temporary table

```
 select p.name, max(tot) 
 from ( p.name, count(* ) as tot 
     from Party p, Delegate d 
     where p.id = d.party 
     group by p.name ) as t;
```